# SDK and Broadlink scenes

Tags: automation, scene

I installed the "Google Assistant SDK" integration and I can send commands to Google Assistant from HA. But I have two questions:

1. If I try to trigger the GA automations that call Broadlink scenes nothing happens... Has anyone managed to do this?
2. If I click on "Assist" at the top right, the chat opens but the assistant's answer is always "I am sorry I did not understand"... Does it work for you?

Thanks to anyone who can/will help me

I try to trigger GA automations that call Broadlink scenes but nothing happens